# Show two alert boxes on single submit event click

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>    
    $('#form_131 > input[type=submit]').click(function(){       
        alert('Jquery alert');
    });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset='utf-8'> 
function testrun()
{
    alert('Test run javascript');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form_131">    
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" onclick="testrun()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a code something like this. I dont have the control on the onclick event of the submit button because it is autogenerated on server side by CMS. I need to add click event for the box and add some validation to text. How can I do that.

Comment: Put the jQuery code in a document ready handler (or in a script block at the end of the body).

Comment: So any error you getting from this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two things you can do:

call your validation function from `testrun`:

```
<script>    
function validateText(){      
   alert('Jquery alert');
}
function testrun()
{
    validateText();
    alert('Test run javascript');
}
</script>
```

or put ready function:

```
<script>   
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#form_131 > input[type=submit]').click(function(){       
      alert('Jquery alert');
   }); 
});
function testrun()
{       
    alert('Test run javascript');
}
</script>
```